# Отправка фотографии POST'ом

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, multipart

Здравствуйте, пишу бота для Вконтакте, проблема в заливке картинки на сервера вк для личных сообщений, заливаю так:

```
getPhoto('/1.jpg', $token);

function getPhoto($path, $token)
{
    $res = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getMessagesUploadServer?v=5.73&access_token='.$token),true)['response'];
    echo $res['upload_url']."\n";
    $post_data = array("file1" => dirname(__FILE__).$path);
    print_r($res);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $res['upload_url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
    print_r($result);
}
```

После первого запроса на сервера вк, мы получаем

```
Array
(
    [upload_url] => https://pu.vk.com/c841226/upload.php?act=do_add&mid=************&aid=-64&gid=**********&hash=31e0f998f1111bddbd6e958ed45a21fb&rhash=222628001029a7ec21ea6a1494491b82&swfupload=1&api=1&mailphoto=1
    [album_id] => -64
    [group_id] => ***************
)
```

Потом на `upload_url` я POST запросом отправляю картинку
Делаю вот так:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $res['upload_url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
```

На выходе в переменой `$result` будет:

```
Array
(
    [server] => 841226
    [photo] => []
    [hash] => 62cd72013627d732c2f61ecbcfde8dac
)
```

Но объект `photo`, не должен быть пустым, т.к. его нужно использовать для - сохранения картинки на серверах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP < 5.5**

До этой версии, для передачи файлов с помощью CURL необходимо доьавлять `@` к пути файла (как это сделано в нативном cURL). Т.е. в вашему случае:

```
$post_data = array("file1" => '@' . dirname(__FILE__) . $path);
```

**PHP >= 5.5**

В версии 5.5 был введён класс [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) для загрузки файлов, а подход с добавлением `@` был объявлен как Deprecated (и удалён в PHP 7.0).

Теперь загрузка файлов с помощью curl выглядит так:

```
$file1 = new CurlFile(dirname(__FILE__) . $path, 'image/jpg');
$post_data = array("file1" => $file1);
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload) и [здесь](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt).

В версиях **PHP 5.5** - **5.6** всё ещё можно использовать старый подход с `@`, но необходимо явно указывать параметр `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
```

Comment: Используется PHP/7.0.27, сейчас перепробую все предложные варианты, если нет, сменю версию

Comment: @ВременныйАккаунт версию не нужно менять. Всё что ниже 7.0 уже давно морально устарело. Используйте подход с CURLFile.

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек! Потратил кучу времени на эту "фичу", Все работает, спасибо <3. *с 23 февраля*